# how to change this regex "/^[0-9]+$/m"?

Tags: php

```
<title>mylogin</title>
<body>
<form action="sql.php" method="POST">
User ID: <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid"/><br/>
Password:  <input type="text" id="password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
</body>
```

and my code sql.php is

```
<?php
include('..\db.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($dbsrvname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if (!$con){
     echo("Connection ERROR");
     die(print_r(mysqli_error($con)));
   }
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/m", $_POST["userid"])){
    die("ONLY numbers allowed");
    }
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE id=" . 
     $_POST["userid"] . " AND password='" .
     mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["password"]) . "';";
$stms = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ($stms === false){
    echo("ERROR during query execution: ");
    die(print_r(mysqli_error($con))); 
    }
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($stms, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($row){
    die("Logged in");
    }
else{
    die("Wrong username or password");}
```

?>

when in this code

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+/", $_POST["userid"])){
    die("ONLY numbers allowed");
}
```

in this code when I input the first number and after this any char like 9a 
the statement (if) is false and continues without printing "only allowed numbers"

but in this statement

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/m", $_POST["userid"])){
    die("ONLY numbers allowed");
}
```

when I input 9a or any first number with char like 9a the statement is true and prints "only allowed numbers"

What is the input value I should enter to make the statement (false) and not go inside the if statement which is printing the allowed numbers?

Comment: `^[0-9]+$` The `^` means beginning of line and `$` is end of line.

Comment: What does it do now and what do you want it to do?

Comment: ok 
What is the input value I should enter to make the statement (false) and not go inside the if statement which is printing the allowed numbers?

if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/m", $_POST["userid"])){
    die("ONLY numbers allowed");
}

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Regex at all.

```
if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userid", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT))
    die ("ONLY numbers allowed");
```

Comment: ok my broth how to hacking this if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/m", $_POST["userid"])){
    die("ONLY numbers allowed");
    }

Comment: Remove the multiline qualifier (m) at the end `"/^[0-9]+$/"`

Answer (score 0):

An input such as:

```
$_POST["userid"] = '1234
--\'';
```

would pass your regex because the first line is only numbers. The `m` checks line by line. You want the whole string to be numerical though.

It would be easier to just check for a non-numeric value anywhere in the string:

```
if (empty($_POST["userid"]) || preg_match("/\D/", $_POST["userid"])){
     die('You entered an unacceptable string');
```

For the SQL part though you'd be much better off using parameterized queries. You also should not store plain text passwords.

See:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
3. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: ok 
What is the input value I should enter to make the statement (false) and not go inside the if statement which is printing the allowed numbers?

if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/m", $_POST["userid"])){
    die("ONLY numbers allowed");
}

Comment: ...or upon re-reading this you are looking for the value that is passed to it to bypass that test. Please see updated answer.